# rails how do i configure assets:precompile for creating files inside public/javascript or /public/stylesheets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

i have a rails application that i want to deploy on my production server,

the thing is that when i run rake assets:precompile, it generates css and js files under /public/assets , for example "/public/assets/application.css" and "/public/assets/application.js"

but when i add this tags on my erb

`<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>`

`<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>`

and i run the site, they both refer to

"mysyte/javascript/application.js"
and
"mysite/stylesheets/application.css"

so, the question is, how do i configure the app so that when i precompile my assets they are place inside "/public/javascript", "/public/stylesheets", and "/public/images"

thanks in advance.

EDIT:

i guess the real problem is that on production the following tag

`<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>`
is refering to "www.mydomain.com/javascript/application.js"

how do i change it to refer to 
"www.mydomain.com/assets/application.js"

Comment: what version of Rails are you using?

Comment: so can i ask why you want everything in public, why not use the asset pipeline thats built into rails? just curious on that one

Comment: i understand that on production mode, the files are not served from app/assets but from public/assets, as apache or nginx are supossed to serve them.

Comment: I haven't come across this before, have you tried deploying without precompiling your assets?

Comment: i deploy by doing an rsync to my amazon ec2 instance, do you recommend another method?

Comment: if everything is in app/assets then just deploy, pretty sure it will be ok, any problems let us know, but putting assets in public folders is not really the practice since asset pipeline

Comment: i don't have my assets on public/assets, in my computer, where i write the code, all the assets are under app/assets, the thing is that when i deploy that code to my ec2 instance running passenger over apache, the  stylesheets tags or javascript tags look for those files under www.mydomain.com/javascript/application.js and they cannot be found

Comment: ah right, sorry i understand now... see if this helps http://merbist.com/2011/08/30/deploying-a-rails-3-1-app-gotchas/

Comment: I don't understand this. What config option did you set in Rails to get a path like `javascript/...` from `javascript_include_tag`?

Comment: i didn't touch anything in the configuration it just points there.

Comment: my production.rb looks like this config.cache_classes = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this)
  config.serve_static_assets = false

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS
  config.assets.compress = true

  # Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
  config.assets.compile = false

  # Generate digests for assets URLs
  config.assets.digest = true

Answer (score 0):

i've solved this,

the thing is that i'm using mongoid on my app, and had to remove active_record
so in my application.rb

i removed `require "rails/all"`
and in change i added

```
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "active_resource/railtie"
require "rails/test_unit/railtie"
```

i was missing

```
require "sprockets/railtie"
```

now my app is searching for assets in the right assets folder.

thanks richlewis and deefour for your time.